# Is there a way to use an "unlift" style when writing in a monad transformer do block?

Tags: haskell, refactoring, monads, monad-transformers

Many monad transformers in Haskell only add one single function to the base monad, for example:

```
MaybeT     adds   mzero
ExceptT    adds   throwE
Producer   adds   yield
Consumer   adds   await
```

So in a `IO`-heavy or complicated-nested monad, I would usually end up writing a `do`-block like this

```
do
    liftIO $ ...
    liftIO $ ...
    if ...
      then
        liftIO $ ...
      else
        mzero
    liftIO $ ...
    liftIO $ ...
    liftIO $ ...
```

which is very unnecessary considering I'm probably just using `mzero` for that one particular statement. Wouldn't it be nice if I could instead only "unlift" when necessary and write the rest of the block normally? Imagine I could write

```
lift $ do
    ...
    ...
    if ...
      then
        ...
      else
        unlift $ mzero
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

I know the above code wouldn't make sense because the `do`-block being lifted is going to be a normal monad and the special effects will not be there, but is there a way to achieve something to a similar effect in Haskell?

Comment: You could probably do this sort of thing with some TH horrors, but have you checked out `lifted-base`?

Comment: I don't think this can't be achieved since monad transformers are not generally invertible (You can't go from `IO (Maybe a)` to `Maybe (IO a)`, for example). On the other hand, `do { liftIO k; liftIO k' }` is equivalent to `liftIO $ do { k ; k' }` so some simplification is possible, and you can make your IO actions into `MonadIO` actions (see `lifted-base` per @dfeuer) so that the lifting is already applied and `liftIO` isn't needed at the use site.

Comment: Perhaps a silly suggestion, but you could try mixing in `Maybe` with a `Just $ do $ ...` to indicate going ahead with a lifted operation, and `Nothing` to indicate an unlifted `mzero`.

Comment: Why not write code using monad type classes? With `MonadError ()` and `MonadIO` it will be: `do { ioAction1; ioAction2; if ... then throwError () else pure () }`?

Comment: If you have multiple `liftIO` calls in a row they can be combined into a single block: `liftIO x; liftIO y; liftIO z;` can be written as `liftIO $ do { x; y; z; }`. Depending on the current monad instance it can also change (typically improving) performance.

Comment: how would effects (e.g. the PureScript ones) deal with this situatiom?